# Question about Galois Theory and Cyclic Extension.

Tags: galois-theory

I'm studying Galois Theory and I was thinking about something. If I have a Cyclic extension $F/E$ then $[F:E]< \infty?$

Remember that $F/E$ is a cyclic extension if $Gal(F/E)$ is cyclic and $F/E$ is galois (it doesn't implies $F/E$ finite, we just have $F/E$ normal and separable).

Comment: I’m not sure (my infinite Galois theory is rusty) but I think that all Galois groups of Galois extensions are profinite, ie the inverse limit of their finite quotients. If so, then the infinite cyclic group isn’t profinite so the extension must be finite.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "cyclic" in the infinite case. As Mindlack says, a Galois group must be profinite, and infinite profinite groups are uncountable, so $\mathbb{Z}$ is never a Galois group.

However, the profinite completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ does occur as a Galois group (for example of any finite field), and we might say that such an extension is "topologically cyclic" in the sense that $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as a dense subgroup.